# Correct way to use Service for network communcation

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-context

I have classes MainActivity and MyService. In service I connect with a server, but I also need to update some UI for which I would need Context from MainActivity. More precisely I need to use a layoutInflater and then update the views. Should this be done separately?
Example of one function

```
 private suspend fun setStations(serverText: String) {
    withContext(Main) {
        for (i in (1..numStations(serverText)))
        {
            frame = ScrollView( ) //would need context here
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_layout, frame) 
            .
            .
            .
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would want to separate your business logic and UI concerns as much as possible, to make the code more readable and testable. To do so, you can follow architectural patters such as MVP, MVVM or MVI, based on the need and complexity of your app.

Thus, in your case you can potentially have a callback setup in your activity,  that is called when the service finishes executing its code.

For reference, here are a few great reads for this:

- https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html
- https://antonioleiva.com/clean-architecture-android/

Also, here's a sample project that uses MVVM (a pretty common architecture)
https://github.com/skydoves/Pokedex

Answer (score 0):

Typically, such a relationship is organized by the architectural pattern (model view presenter). You should make requests to the server in the presenter and then refer to Activity. This might help you https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy